# Is there an equivalent to Table Notifications in System.Runtime.Caching

Tags: .net

I am migrating from System.Web.Caching to the newer (.NET 4) System.Runtime.Caching namespace. However there does not seem to be an equivalent to the old SqlCacheDependency table notifications architecture. With SqlCacheDependency you can get notifications when data in a table changes, simply by specifying the table name. Is there a different way that table change notifications can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that there is no equivalent - this feature has been left out of System.Runtime.Caching. With some effort it could in theory be re-built, perhaps as an open source project by an enterprising developer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of SqlChangeMonitor class.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.sqlchangemonitor.aspx),

> The SqlChangeMonitor class wraps the ADO.NET SqlDependency class and
> adds change monitoring for SQL Server-based dependencies. Therefore,
> the SqlChangeMonitor class serves as a bridge between the ADO.NET
> SqlDependency object and the System.Runtime.Caching namespace.

The SQLChangeMonitor needs to be added to ChangeMonitors, via CacheItemPolicy object. Then, you can associate the CacheItemPolicy with MemoryCache using Add or Set method.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't explain how to get notifications when data in table changes like you can with SqlCacheDependency.

Comment: you to use SQLDependency in SqlChangeMonitor. Msdn link :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The link shows how to enable command-based notifications, however that is considerably more complex to implement than the old table-based notifications.